# What does 素 mean in 素数?

Tags: translation, word

Composite number is translated as 合数, which do make sense; 
Prime number is called 素数, what does 素 means here?

Is it possible to trace the source of such translation?

Comment: OP cross-posted this same question to [Japanese SE](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73436). Anyways, your question appears answered on p. 241 of *Christopher Seeley's Complete Guide to Japanese Kanji*, 2006 2nd ed. >![](https://i.imgur.com/yag9fiF.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「素」generically means *basal, essential, intrinsic, primal*. Hence you have vocabulary like

- 元素 (*atom*), the fundamental constituent of matter (well, the name was given before they discovered subatomic particles)
- 詞素 (*morpheme*), the fundamental constituent of words
- 要素 (*essential factor*)

Comment: It 's very interesting to find that google translate `primer number' to '素数' in Japanese. So it borrowed from Japanese. Do you know some Japanese about the word 素?

Comment: atom is reasonable,  prime number can not be decomposed any more.

Comment: @Algebra well「素」in Japanese shares the *base, primal* meanings with Chinese. As for whether 素數 originated in Japanese, I'm not sure. They might have coined it - there's a heap of words in Chinese that originated from [*Wasei-Kango*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasei-kango).

Answer (score 2):

素 can mean *prime in  some way*. See this definition in dictionaries:

> 带有根本性质的物质或构成事物的基本成分。
>
> 元素；毒素；因素；要素

Answer (score 1):

素 can mean 物的基本成分 (basic element of something) as an extension from its base meaning of plain, natural, pure, unmodified.

In its synonym 质数, 质 also means the nature of something or being plain and simple.

Answer (score 1):

素数 is a Japanese mathematic term for "prime number", which equates to the Chinese term "质数" - the natural numbers greater than 1, that have only two factors, one and the number itself.

Note that "质" has the meaning of "单纯", which is also reflected by 素 - a pure, unmodified element, such as "朴素", "元素".

[素数（そすう、英: primeあるいはprime number）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B4%A0%E6%95%B0)